# Looking for Calculus exercise book with really good and complete solutions

Tags: calculus

I have the "Calculus 3-d Edition, Michael Spivak". The book itself is really nice, it explains the stuff very well. However, not all sample problems in the book have their solutions in the "answers" sections. Many are left out. Unfortunately, it is really hard to understand whether you've provided a correct solution if you don't have an example/answer. I've found that there are few separate "answer" books but they seem to be low-rated by the ones who bought them.

Can someone please suggest a good Calculus exercise book(containing only/mostly problems) with a **good and complete (i.e. with solutions to all provided problems)** answers section?

Comment: There does exists a Spivak answer book, called "Supplement to Calculus".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer really depends on what your intention is.

If your intention is to get by the class by solving millions of examples and learning through them, here are a few references. However, it is almost impossible to find a good book which provides answers for each and every sum.

- [Schaum's 3000 Calculus Solved](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071635343) (Not great, there are a few mistakes here and 
  there)
- [Schaum's Calculus](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0070419736) (Plenty of practice problems, need not be with solutions though)
- Just enough solved examples in [Banner's](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0691130884) awesome book (I love this book. But I use it for review, not for learning. So, take my advice with some skepticism).
- [Humongous book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1592575129) (No comments).

---

If your intention is to learn, I'd recommend trying to formulate your solutions and ask on Math.SE if you have any problems.

You could use Apostol, Spivak, Stewart or whatever (Depending on your comfort of rigour)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there a particular reason why exercise books providing 200 or 3000 problems do not include answers to all of them? I've myself never seen any such book with complete answer set. The problem is that many times I solve something but I can't be sure that there is no logical "leak" in my solution and there is simply nothing to compare to.

Comment: I would suggest that you try to find out by yourself if there is a leak indeed. This will develop intuition. If you want to check whether your integration is correct, differentiate the answer and see if you get the result. The 10 minutes you spend in this will be more fruitful than glancing at the answer and patting yourself on the back :) Regarding your question, it is sometimes impossible to sit and calculate answers for 3000 problems for the author let aside making sure they are all correct.

Comment: Anyways, you can view a preview of the Schaum's book on [google books](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=5ECPg8Ldp4IC&printsec=frontcover&dq=schaum+3000&hl=en&sa=X&ei=sGVbT9jvMcPqrQfH89jtCw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=schaum%203000&f=false). Seems like Hints and Answers are given for most (if not all) problems.

Comment: It is very much possible to calculate answers for 3000 problems. Hire a couple of undergrads and tell them to solve all the problems, then compare their answers. The real answer is, that costs more money.

Answer (score 5):

The all-time champion in calculus exercise books is sadly out of print and costs a king's ransom to own now: B.P. Demidovich's *Problems in mathematical analysis*. There are thousands of exercises in calculus here-many solved, many with complete solutions in the text and whatever problems don't have complete solutions, the answers are given in the back of the book. They run the gamut in diversity and difficulty from simple computations to more difficult geometric or analytic computations to theoretical problems at the level of advanced calculus. It was originally in Russian, but a translation appeared in the 1960's. It's still used by many of the top schools across the world as a study aid. Sadly,it's become very hard to find in printed copy now. 
(Of course,if you're inventive and can locate a copy online in either PDF or DJVU, I tip my hat to your resourcefulness without either approving or condemning your illegal activities..............)

Comment: Would this book have problems similar to what's tested on the Putnam, HMIC, or any other problem-solving exams? (and it is not very difficult to find such a PDF. . . not that I ever did such a thing, of course.)

Comment: Since the English translations were done by Mir in the USSR, I think those old editions should actually be in the public domain now, so downloading them should be completely legal. However, I can't find anything reliable about their precise publication dates.

Comment: yes they are public domain and available for download from archive.org

Answer (score 0):

I have Thomas and Finney 4th edition 1981 Elements of Calculus and Analytic Geometry.  It is very strong on applied problems and has lots of good derivations also.  It has 100% of the answers (not worked solutions, but answers, which I usually find to be enough given the text is full of worked examples).  You can get used copies very cheaply on Amazon.

[https://www.amazon.com/dp/0201076640/?tag=stackoverflow17-20](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201076640)

FYI, this is the book that is shown in the movie Stand and Deliver and teacher Jaime Escalante wrote that it was his favorite text.

I believe it is the last edition before Thomas stopped working on the texts and turned into a brand name instead.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  It is a matter of StackExchange policy that answers should provide support for claims, not mere recollections or speculation.  Given the time that passed since this Question was posted, there is time to verify and support your suggestions.